# Python 3 recursive method returning last value not current value

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am a little stumped on this one. I am doing a leet code problem for removing duplicate chars from a string. I took a recursive approach to this problem however my output is not following the expected behavior and im not to sure why. Hoping someone on here could explain what i'm missing.

input: s = "azxxzy"
expected output: "ay"

Explaination: When looking at azxxzy, we first remove the adjacent xx chars. Which leaves you with azzy. Then you can remove zz, leaving you only with ay with no other duplicate characters adjacent to each other.

The code I wrote to accomplish this.

```
def removeDuplicates(s: str):
    i =  0
    while i < len(s) - 1:
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            s = s.replace(s[i] + s[i+1], '')
            removeDuplicates(s)
        i += 1
    return s
```

This is returning "azzy" as the result.

However if I put in some print statments to track the value of s. it appears to be working properly until return statment.

```
def removeDuplicates(self, s: str) -> str:
    i =  0
    print(s)
    while i < len(s) - 1:
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            s = s.replace(s[i] + s[i+1], '')
            removeDuplicates(s)
        i += 1
    print(s)
    return s
```

returns:

```
azxxzy    - Starting Value
azzy      - Value after first recursive call
ay        - Value after second recursive call
ay        - No duplicates found, so it just prints the value of s
ay        - No duplicates found, so it just prints the value of s
azzy      - Python decides it wants to grab the last value of s for some reason!?!
```

Comment: Removing adjacent duplicates won't work if you have "azxzxy".

Comment: @j1-lee that did the trick. Totally overlooked that since the value was getting updated in the print statements as expected.

Comment: @DavidLee thats correct, it is only supposed to remove the characters where there are adjacent duplicates, not just duplicate values. Sorry if i did not make that clear In your example there are no adjacent duplicates so the return value would just be azxzxy.

Comment: Even the recursive version finally works, it's not very efficient.  Use **stack** to track the duplicates would be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to j1-lee for the explaination. I was not returning the results of the recursive function call. The below code is now working as expected.

```
def removeDuplicates(self, s: str) -> str:
    i =  0

    while i < len(s) - 1:
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            s = s.replace(s[i] + s[i+1], '')
            s = removeDuplicates(s)
        i += 1

    return s
```